# Azure Data Factory querying Mongo DB to filter on Dates

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory

I am querying a mongoDB from ADFv2 and I am trying to filter the data based on dates. However the date appears in a random string of numbers. Just wondering if there there is a way to filter the data dynamically in the source of the copy task as I am trying to load the data in an incremental fashion.

```
    [
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5d5123dc8cf0b4453ceb2088"
    },
    "TemplateId": "5d3ac5c77eb20a2cf4bdf46a",
    "LastUpdate": {
      "$date": 1565603495299
    },
    "Answers": [
      {
        "Question": "Q001c",
        "Answer": {
          "_t": "System.String[]",
          "_v": [
            "0,In person"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "Question": "Q001a",
        "Answer": {
          "_t": "System.String[]",
          "_v": [
            "0,Yes"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "Question": "Q003a",
        "Answer": {
          "_t": "System.String[]",
          "_v": [
            "0,Yes"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "Question": "Q006a",
        "Answer": {
          "_t": "System.String[]",
          "_v": [
            "1,No"
          ]
```

The SInk/Destination is into a SQL database. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying there is no consistent way to find the $date element?

Comment: I would like to filter on the $date to restrict the volume of data if that makes sense

Comment: Is date laways at `[0].LastUpdate.$date`? What have you tried?

Comment: I havent tried anything as I cannot make sense of the date '1565603495299' for that particular example, not sure what you mean but all records have a date and I would imagine the first record would start from [0]. THe date is what I am having problems trying to filer on as possibly maybe something like unix timestamps or something which needs converting in ADF at soure ideally to restrict the data in the sink.

Comment: This is something you should have mentioned in the original question. Do you have a rough idea what date that is representing, i.e. is it something in recent times? like in the last four years?

Comment: When I paste that number in here it gives me a date in 2019 - is that what you're expecting? https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: If the objective is to "load the data in an incremental fashion." then it doesn't even matter what that number represents, as long is it's guaranteed to be incremental. Just store the number as is as your high water mark.

Comment: Did you try taking the max of date from the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I repro'd the incremental loading of data from MongoDb to SQL DB using ADF. As @Nick.Mc.Dermaid suggested, max of timestamp value should be given as watermark value for incremental data load.  Approach that followed here is to copy all the data with date greater than watermark value and to update the watermark value with max of date.  So that in next pipeline run, delta data will be copied. Below are the detailed steps.

- In MongoDB API, two documents are inserted into a container.
  [image]
- Then In SQL database, Watermark table is created as in below image with `watermark value =1000000000000`.
  [image]
  The value for watermark is set as above, so that in first run all data from source gets loaded into sink.
- A stored procedure is written in SQL database to update the watermark table with latest date value.

```sql
create proc usp_update_watermark_table as
begin
update watermark
set watermarkvalue=(select max(LastUpdate) from tgt_table)
end
```

- In ADF, Lookup activity is taken and watermark table is referred in that.
  `select WatermarkValue from watermark`

[image]

- Copy activity is taken next to lookup activity. In Source dataset, MongoDB API is taken and in filter , below expression is given to copy the data that are greater than the value from lookup activity.

```sql
{"LastUpdate":{$gt:@{activity('LookupLastWaterMark').output.firstRow.WatermarkValue}}}
```

[image]

- Stored procedure activity is added next to copy activity. So that new value gets updated in watermark table.
  [image]
- After pipeline run, the output table and watermark table is updated.
  [image]
- New Document is added in source
  [image]
- When pipeline is triggered again, only delta record got loaded to sink.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you both and thank you Aswin, just one last question, is there a way to change the value of the date from say 1565603495299 to actual yyyy-mm-dd from adf using expression from the source, as i would need to convert to an actual date for reporting purposes downstream.

Comment: You need to use Dataflow for that. In derived transformation, you can create a column abd give the value as toTimeStamp(col1)

Comment: Otherwise, you can convert it using sql queries, after copying it into SQL database.

Comment: ahh okay, I am really new to ADF and NoSQL and haven't used dataflow, so as a quick turnaround will do it on SQL at destination. Thank you again much appreciated :o)